# SQL to capture running total in addition to maintaining FIFO attributes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fifo, inventory

I'm an average skilled SQL developer experience with SQL and ETL applications around data warehousing applications, I am struggling with SQL logic to reduce an inventory amount by how much of a material was used as it's more OLTP / transactional centric.

I have a 2 tables, Order and Application

**Orders**
OrderId
Date
MaterialId
Amount

**Application** 
AppId
AppDate
BlockId
Material
MaterialId
Amount

*Application*  documents usage of materials by distinct agriculture blocks
*Orders* records orders which procured the material. There can be products on an order that I am not interested in, I may need an intermediary table to only store materials. *MaterialID* is a common key between both tables.

[Example of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHbNG.png)

Use case is that materials are perpetually ordered for use on agricultural field, we're trying to track usage against inventory - its important to tie usage back to an order for food safety.

I've attempted a running total by joining the tables for a running total (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436485/how-to-subtract-inventory-and-sale-using-mysql-subquery) StackOverflow post), however, the approach is agnostic to a new order of same material when the amount of the previous order is depleted -  I can't figure how to stop capturing the former `OrderId` of the material and start capturing the new `OrderId`. I think more to the schema may be needed.

Guidance on a new approach to this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Based on the names involved, i would say you have **views** not tables. That might not be important - and it might be. Start by providing a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your reader does not need to guess at the actual relationships and keys in your schema. And your use case is suspicious. You can't use what has been ordered but not received, right? Are you certain you have the needed information?

Comment: I edited and tried simplifying. I had views originally as this was a POC and I needed to join the order header and detail. This is how the final solution would look - were in the process of building the schema. If there is a record in the Order table the material has been received and can be used. While that amount is being used a new order may be received of the same material in anticipation for new application needs. For some applications I may finish using material from one order and pick up using material from the newest order. Is that more clear?